# What are some altruistic reasons for submitting to top-tier journals/conferences?

Tags: publications, ethics

It seems to me that there is a preoccupation within academia to getting published in venues which are highest-ranked in terms of some sort of metrics rather than venues most suited to one’s subject area albeit not high-ranked.

It occurred to me that any reason for this must be self-serving. I don’t feel comfortable with this idea. As opposed to self-interest as the actual motive, are there any better reasons for submitting to top-tier journals/conferences rather than low-tier ones?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  Journal publications are not an act of altruism under any circumstances that I can think of.

Comment: I agree with Pete Clark. Or to reword that, please define altruism (a word that is used in somewhat different ways at least in philosophy). It's hard to imagine circumstances where an individual actor motivated by altruism would think the best outlet of that is submitting to "top-tier journal/conferences"

Comment: I have edited my question. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Well, if you think your results are very useful to a broad audience and you want as many people as possible to know them for the advancement of the field, then the greater reach and audience of the more renowned journal would be an advantage.

Comment: @GDumphart, good answer. But does the more renowned journal necessarily have the greater reach of audience? And the more renowned journal is not necessarily the higher-ranked either.

Comment: @adipro I think this is hard to tell in days where many people find literature with Google Scholar instead of browsing the newest issues of their your journals of choice. But there is definitely a tendency towards articles in renowned journals getting more citations (authors want to increase their acceptance odds with "strong" references, b/c there are indeed some reviewers who will reject papers whose references are not mostly top journals 2013-2016), thus getting assigned higher index or relevance (or whatever) by search engines like Google Scholar, and thus getting more exposure and reach.

Comment: There is a false dichotomy in your question. People don't choose highly ranked venues *instead* of most suited ones.

Comment: I would turn the question around: is there anything more altruistic about submitting to mid-tier venues than to top-tier venues? The answer is no. The two actions are equally (un)altruistic.

Comment: @CapeCode, people in my field do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By submitting your work to highly ranked, prestigious journals, you are typically confronting it with the strictest scrutiny and highest standards in the profession. You also accept that the novelty of your work will be judged by experienced researchers of your field. That's how journals get their reputation and rank.

The consequences are that you will have the very valuable opportunity to improve your work by receiving reviews or rejections. When your work will be accepted you'll have made a significant contribution to your field.

Submitting your work to journals that have lower acceptance standards, or pay-to-publish megajournals with no desk-rejection, you are possibly (and I mean possibly because I can't judge your work) watering down the literature with redundant or irrelevant material.

So yes, by aiming high and accepting that your work could eventually not be worth publishing there, you are doing the scientific community a favor. That's altruistic.

Also if you're an established researcher who do not need the exposure and prestige anymore to secure your career moves, you might have co-authors that are not that far yet. Making sure your common work gets the attention and scrutiny it deserves is common sense to me but also altruistic.

Comment: Your 1st paragraph implies that there are different pools of reviewers, where the higher-ranked journals draw from the higher-quality pool of reviewers and so on. I'd like to think that this is true, but I am not sure if I can. I mean, what can stop a lower-ranked journal from soliciting reviews from high-quality reviewers? Anyway, thank you for a good answer.

Comment: @adipro I interpret it more as high-ranked, prestigious journals get more submissions compared to others so the bar is set higher as they have to filter out more than for lower-ranked publications.

Answer (score 5):

[Wrzlprmft's good answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/68643/24098) hints at this, but I want to make it explicit:

**If you are doing beneficial research, your self-interest and the interests of beneficiaries of your research are aligned.**

If your work is important, then the visibility of your work and your own career success benefit others, since they maximize the impact of your research and ensure that you will have resources and freedom to do the best work going forward.

Ambition is neither good nor bad.  What matters is: *to what end is your ambition directed?*

I agree that simply getting recognition, as an end in itself, is not a worthy goal.  But if you are in your career in order to make a difference in the world with the research you conduct, then trying to advance your own career to achieve that goal is worthwhile (and necessary).

**What about submission to top journals specifically?**

There are pros and cons of aiming for the top, in terms of maximizing the impact of the work.  The pros are well covered in other answers, but in summary, the main ones are:

- Wider visibility.
- Better basis on which to build your own future work.
- Higher review standards.

However, *there are also downsides to aiming high:*

- **Delay in publication**.  If you aim for a top journal, and then try a sequence of high impact journals until you find one that accepts it, this can delay publication by many months.  Meanwhile, your work is not being read by anyone and not having an impact.  And you can't apply for further funding based on the work until it is out there.
- **Perhaps not the best use of your time.**  Is it a good use of your time to endlessly revise a paper and tweak your analysis in response to reviewer suggestions?  Or would it be better to get on to the next research question?
- **Papers may be less accessible than if published as open access.**  Some top journals are not open access, and publishing in a lower-impact (but open access) journal may increase the accessibility of your work.

Ultimately, you have to weight the costs versus the benefits, particularly in light of the likelihood that your work will be accepted at a top journal.  Personally, I don't like the all-too-frequent practice of starting at the top journal and working downward, even if the paper has little chance of success.  I think this is a big waste of time and resources.  But for a result that is really noteworthy, it may be worth submitting to high-impact journals (not just for your sake, but to maximize the benefit of the work).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your publication is indeed sufficiently exceptional to be published in the respective journal:

1. As [already mentioned in a comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68637/what-are-some-altruist-reasons-for-submitting-to-top-tier-journal-conferences#comment167095_68637), high-ranked journals have a higher visibility *outside* your specific subfield. This applies to scientists of related disciplines who may translate your work to their field, but also to news coverage and similar that communicates the achievements of science to the general public. Indeed many high-ranking journals have a criterion that your work is of general interest beyond your specific subfield.

   While this attention benefits you, it also allows the scientific community and the general public to benefit from your insights more than a publication in a lower-ranking journal does. Moreover the additional attention may benefit your field or subfield by highlighting its usefulness to funding organisations and students who might venture into this field. Finally, it slightly benefits science in general by communicating it usefulness to the general public.
2. If your results are not entirely based on luck, they may indicate that you are indeed a comparably capable scientist and funding you is more likely to advance mankind than funding somebody else. Thus your egoistic interests are to some extent also altruistic. Or with other words: The academic system’s evaluation mechanisms are based on high-ranking publications and getting people properly evaluated helps science and academia. By not participating in this system, you are harming it.

Now, there is some criticism on the idea of ranking journals at all in times of the Internet where hardly anybody reads articles by journal anymore, and one may consider it more ethical to fight and boycott this system than participating in it due to the above reasons. But that’s a decision you have to make for yourself and this platform is not fit for discussing it.

Comment: Thank you for a good answer. In relation to your point 1, I tend to think that generalist journals are not likely to scrutinize your work as detailed as the more specialized journals, is this not true?

Comment: @adipro: Not at all. Generalist journals will still select reviewers from your subfield, but high-ranking journals usually use more reviewers and sometimes also have stricter rules on past collaborations between authors and reviewers.